# scikit-learn undersampling of unbalanced data for crossvalidation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How do I generate random folds for cross-validation in scikit-learn?

Imagine we have 20 samples of one class, and 80 of the other, and we need to generate N train and test sets, each train set of the size 30, under the constraint that in each training set, the we have 50% of class one and 50% of class 2.

I found this discussion (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1362) but I don't understand how to get folds. Ideally I think I need such a function:

```
cfolds = np.cross_validation.imaginaryfunction(
[list(itertools.repeat(1,20)), list(itertools.repeat(2,80))], 
n_iter=100, test_size=0.70)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why not just use `random.sample()`?

Comment: for the same reason we have all other cross_validation function!?

Comment: You can define your own cross-validation generator: it should be an object with an `__len__` that returns `N` and an `__iter__` that yields `N` pairs of lists `(train_indices, test_indices)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do crossvalidation with undersampling in scikit, but there are two workarounds:

1.

Use `StratifiedCrossValidation` to achieve cross validation with distribution in each fold mirroring the distribution of data, then you can achieve imbalance reduction in classifiers via the `class_weight` param which can either take `auto` and undersample/oversample classes inversely proportional to their count or you can pass a dictionary with explicit weights.

2.

Write your own cross validation routine, which should be pretty straight forward using [pandas](http://manishamde.github.io/blog/2013/03/07/pandas-and-python-top-10/).

Answer (score 0):

StratifiedCV is a good choice but you can make it simpler:

1. Run random sampling on data related to class 1 (you need select 15/20 samples)
2. The same for class 2 (15/80)
3. Repeat 100 times or how much you need.

That's all. Quick and workable!